# How to prove $\int_0^x \sin(t) (x - t)^m \mathrm d t \geq 0$

Tags: integration

I want to prove

$$\int_0^x \sin(t) (x - t)^m \mathrm d t \geq 0 \, \forall x\in\mathbb R\,\forall m\in\mathbb N.$$

I already tried a couple of things, e.g. induction or estimation of the integral but I didn't come to a proper proof (e.g. I tried to drop the $(x-t)^m > 0$ but that didn't seem to be possible). So how can one prove that?

Comment: As it is stated it is  false. I think you wrote $\sin x$ for $\sin t$.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thanks @KaviRamaMurthy.

Comment: $$\int_0^x(x-t)^m\sin t\,\mathrm dt=m!\mathop{\intop\cdots\intop}\limits_{0<t<t_1<\cdots<t_m<x}\sin t\,\mathrm dt\mathrm dt_1\cdots\mathrm dt_m$$for $x>0$.

Comment: Sorry, i do not know this notation @Saad. What does it mean?

Comment: But if $x=0$ your assertion is false, integral becomes $0$

Comment: Yes, it should be $\geq$. I edited the question.

Comment: If you take $m=1$ your integral reads $x-\sin (x)$ and for $x=-\pi$ (for example) you get $-\pi$ that is not positive.

Comment: May be $x\geq 0$ instead $x\in\mathbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For $m=1$
$$
I_1(x) =\int_0^x \sin(t) (x - t) \mathrm d t = x -\sin x
$$
which is strictly positive only if $x>0$, so I will restrict myself to $x\geq 0$.

You have that 
$$
I_m(x) = \int_0^x \sin(t) (x - t)^m \mathrm d t  \qquad I_m(0) = 0
$$
and it is easy to prove the recurrence relation
$$
\frac{d}{dx} I_m(x) = m I_{m-1}(x)
$$
We also have to consider $I_0(x) = 1-\cos(x) \geq 0$. At this point you can use the recurrence relation to show that every $I_m(x)$ is an increasing function for $x>0$. Since they all start from zero at $x=0$, all the $I_m(x)$ are positive for $x>0$.

Comment: But hypothesis sais $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Take $I_1(x) =x-\sin(x)$, it is not positive for $x<0$, so the statement in the question is false. Therefore, I consider only $x>0$ (probably $x \in \mathbb{R} $ is just a  typo in the question).

Comment: I think is a typo too